# How to select file, fix orientation, and add to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

My site allows users to upload their own photos. I've learned that this is trickier than first expected and although I can get each of the components working individually I'm not successfully getting them to produce the outcome I need when combining them. I believe the issue is my lack of understanding around the outputs of the functions i'm using.

I think what I need to do is:

1. Let the user choose the file to upload
2. Check / fix the orientation
3. Display the image in a canvas
4. Convert the canvas to base64 (to upload to Firebase)
5. Upload the item

**Let the user choose the file to upload**

```
$(document).on('change','#fileUpload',function(e) {
    correctImageOrientation(e);
});
```

**Check / fix the image orientation**

I'm using image-load ([link](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/)) for my orientation changes.

```
function correctImageOrientation(e) {

  loadImage(
      e.target.files[0],
      function (img) {
          // document.body.appendChild(img); // Note: this successfully appends the image in the correct orientation to the body - but I need to do this to a canvas to I call:
          addImageToCanvas(img);
      },
      {
          orientation: true
      }
);
```

**Display the image in a canvas**

This part fails. If I pass in the selected file using e.target.files[0] and create an objectURL then it works. This is why I think the img i'm passing in needs to be read / displayed on the canvas differently.

```
function addImageToCanvas(img) {
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");   

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        console.log("Ending img.onload"); // This is never reached
    }
}
```

I can then successfully convert the file to base64 and upload to Firebase.

I think there must be an easier way to achieve what I want which is for people to upload an image, for the orientation to be correct, and for this to be stored online.

EDIT: To store the image in firebase I am using [this](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) to convert the image back to a blob.

Comment: Firebase Storage allows you to upload files from the web, without the (incredibly wasteful) base64 encoding. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks for the reply. I can upload the image without any issue, but if I first want to correct the orientation then I need to convert it to a canvas to use load-image to do the orientation check. I guess I could then convert it back to an image so I will try that but do you have another suggestion for doing this? e.g. am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced `addImageToCanvas` with the function below which was taken then modified from [David Walsh's site](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image). Because I'm passing in an image I needed to convert this to a canvas.

```
function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```